# LDAP authentication in java with apache LDAP

Tags: java, apache, security, authentication, ldap

Can you provide me with a simple apache LDAP authentication example. following is my sample code snippet.

```
@Bean

CommandLineRunner runner() {
    return args -> {

        LOGGER.info("CommandLineRunner running in the UnsplashApplication class...");

        LdapConnection connection = new LdapNetworkConnection(
                "ldap://server.TEST.COM:389/DC=TEST,DC=COM", 389, false);
        connection.setTimeOut(0);
        LOGGER.info("@@ Trying to connect to LDAP...");

        connection.bind();
        connection.connect();
        LOGGER.info("@@ isConnected: " + connection.isConnected());

        // connection.bind("uid=user,ou=users", "password@123");
        // connection.bind("ou=users,DC=TEST,DC=COM", "password@123");

    };
}
```

Comment: the above code snipet throws error. following is the error log.

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.exception.InvalidConnectionException: Cannot connect to the server: Hostname 'ldap://TEST.COM:389/DC=TEST,DC=COM' could not be resolved.
 at 
 ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException: null
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.connect(LdapNetworkConnection.java:663) ~[api-all-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
 ... 11 common frames omitted

Comment: Make sure that the port 389 is accessible from your machine. telnet is your friend.

Comment: Already did. server is accessible from telnet. Actually I've tried unbound ladp sdk and spring security for LDAP auth but didn't work. Somehow server is not resolving. Kindly help me with some example in java.And please don't mind server.TEST and TEST as its a simple typo error.

Answer (score 0):

```
LdapConnection connection = new LdapNetworkConnection(
            "ldap://server.TEST.COM:389/DC=TEST,DC=COM", 389, false);
```

The first argument to [`LdapNetworkConnection(String, int, boolean)`](https://directory.apache.org/api/gen-docs/latest/apidocs/org/apache/directory/ldap/client/api/LdapNetworkConnection.html#LdapNetworkConnection-java.lang.String-int-boolean-) is a server name, not a URL.

Pretty good clue in

```
Hostname 'ldap://TEST.COM:389/DC=TEST,DC=COM' could not be resolved
```